# Grant select and read to all tables and views (including dbc) in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I can see all views and tables in all databases in Teradata. What is need is to create a role that has select and read to all these tables and views in all tables, all databases and all dbc views.

Any advise? or di i have to grant everything?
What about Granting roles to the role?

I know that on a third layer of role granting it has to be done with ADMIN.

Thanks and regards
A

Comment: You can grant SELECT at the database level (meaning all objects within that database) to a role; yes, you have to grant on each database individually. (Not sure of your distinction between SELECT and "read"; perhaps something to do with the internal AccessRight code value for SELECT being 'R '?)

Comment: Also only two levels of roles are recognized; ADMIN option just gives the right to grant/revoke role membership.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Fred. Yes the Select being R.. I get your first comment regarding the grant SELECT to all objects. And this is what I did. 

So this can be the solution thank you. (just a question for my benefit:) I want to grant Select privileged Roles to this new roles where exist, and where they do not exist (for example if there are no roles with select privilege) I want to grant the select directly. That is also done individually correct? Thanks

Comment: Correct. Permission has to be granted for each database individually.

Comment: Please add it the first comment as an answer so that I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grant SELECT at the database level (meaning all objects within that database) to a role; yes, you have to grant on each database individually.